# What structure would you recommend to use to hold a bunch of String-Object associations?

Tags: java, collections

it'll be used to key-map String-Object value.
let's say, myObject = struct.get("first");
ordering is not important.

parameterized Hashset or anything better?

if that doesn't bother you, can you give me an example of *static initialization* along with the declaration, of a simpler structure, eg (String-String key mapping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your object needs to be threadsafe or not.  If thread safety is not a concern, HashMap is what you want.  If thread safety is required, you can go with ConcurrentHashMap.

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object>();
```

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap<String, Object>` is the way forward.